# Facing NoMethodError in RailsAdmin::MainController#dashboard when trying to configure rails admin for the first time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I am following the official rails admin git hub page to install and configure rails admin on my rails application.

I added

`gem 'rails_admin', '~> 1.2'` on my gem file

and ran `rails g rails_admin:install` and

kept **localhost:3000/admin** as default route.

When I entered **localhost:3000/admin**, I am getting following error

```
NoMethodError in RailsAdmin::MainController#dashboard

private method `all' called for #<Class:0x007f9afe494be8>
```

Comment: did you do bundle install?

Comment: you have not installed latest one  add only this 
only add

gem 'rails_admin'

Answer (score 0):

This is because of some mistakes are done in any model, please cross check your model where you have defined this

```
private method `all' called for #<Class:0x007f9afe494be8>
```

> "all"

method., or just comment this block of code just to test then restart the server and see if it works or not.

Comment: search "def all"

Comment: ok i got it, take out this method from private block , i mean write this method outside private block. :)  this should work.